# Script SSI Injection

Tags: curl, script

Buenas,

estoy tratando de hacer un script para automatizar pruebas de SSI Injection.

La idea es utilizar curl para hacer la petición a un formulario pero me encuentro el problema de que al hacer la petición, es como si la hiciera a la página de login.

He utilizado la cookie que se genera al hacer el login pero sigue sin mandar la petición donde yo quiero.

Pongo un ejemplo de las paginas y del script para ver si se entiende mejor:

La pagina de login es esta:

```
http://192.168.0.103/bWAPP/login.php
```

Y la página a la que quiero hacer la petición es esta:

```
http://192.168.0.103/bWAPP/ssii.php
```

Y este es el script con la cookie:

```
curl --cookie 'PHPSESSID=2ffb41de99abf67ae7732d33af0214b1; security=low' -d 'firstname=prueba&lastname=prueba&form=submit' http://192.168.0.103/bWAPP/ssii.php -o prueba.txt.
```

Para que quede mas claro, cuando hago una petición GET la respuesta es la página de login.. que es previa a la página que yo quiero inyectar.

[image: crawler]

¿Alguien sabe como podría hacerlo en este caso?

Gracias, un saludo!!

Comment: No estoy seguro de si la cookie tiene el formato correcto... has probado a usar `--cookie-jar`? Creo que te simplificaría las cosas

Comment: Si pero estoy en las mismas, yo me logue en la página de login, luego accedo a ssii.php, si lo hiciera con --cookie-jar... ¿no deberia antes guardar la cookie?

Comment: Según entiendo, usando --cookie-jar al hacer el login debería guardar la cookie en el fichero

Comment: Mira si pongo la opcion -D para que me vuelque los headers... me vuelca los headers de la pagina login.php.

Comment: `HTTP/1.1 302 Found

Date: Thu, 30 Nov 2017 13:13:40 GMT

Server: Apache/2.2.8 (Ubuntu) DAV/2 mod_fastcgi/2.4.6 PHP/5.2.4-2ubuntu5 with Suhosin-Patch mod_ssl/2.2.8 OpenSSL/0.9.8g

X-Powered-By: PHP/5.2.4-2ubuntu5

Expires: Thu, 19 Nov 1981 08:52:00 GMT

Cache-Control: no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0

Pragma: no-cache

Location: login.php

Content-Length: 0

Content-Type: text/html`

Comment: El script era este `curl --cookie 'PHPSESSID=ad071bb5d885d1dad5ad8719586decdb; security=low' -d 'firstname=prueba&lastname=prueba&form=submit' http://192.168.0.103/bWAPP/ssii.php -D prueba.txt`

Answer (score 0):

Me ha salido de esta manera (hay que tener en cuenta que los campos pueden variar) también he utilizado la cookie de sesión después de loguearme:

`#curl --cookie 'PHPSESSID=196deae838202ca934004d323887b4c3; security_level=0' -d 'firstname=prueba&lastname=prueba&form=submit' http://192.168.0.106/bWAPP/ssii.php -D prueba.txt`

Espero que le sirva a otro!!

Un saludo.